# AngularJS Update an element only works if one of its property is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My question may be silly as I'm a beginner in JS and AngularJS but I noticed something. I have a list and a function :

```
$scope.persons = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Mark",
        "alive": true
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Tom",
        "alive": true
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Jack",
        "alive": false
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "William",
        "alive": true
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Scott",
        "alive": true
    }, ];
$scope.kill = function(person) {
        person = {
            "id": person.id,
            "name": person.name,
            "alive": !person.alive
        };
    console.log(person);
}
```

This list is used to create a table.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
        <td>Name : {{person.name}}</td>
        <td>Alive? : {{person.alive}}</td>
        <td>
            <button ng-click="kill(person)">{{person.alive?  'Kill' : 'Reborn'}}</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I click the button it is supposed to toggle the value of person.alive. With this code it doesn't work. But, If the functions kill() is :

```
$scope.kill = function (person) {
        person.alive = !person.alive;
        console.log(person);
    }
```

It works ! Did I make a mistake in the first function or is it just normal ?

Regards,

Comment: It is because you've created a new person based upon the person passed to the function rather than changing the original person.

Comment: Ok I see so by doing "this.person.alive = !person.alive" it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the first function that you wrote is that you create a new person instead of modifying the one that was passed to you. The second function you wrote is correct because it modifies the correct property on the existing person.